# UWP arrange Bottom items in vertically(splitview)

Tags: uwp, uinavigationbar

I am working in UWP, I have a split view for navigation view.
I want to arrange bottom items to vertically when I closing the pane.

This is the UI I have before closing the pane

[image: Split view]

I want to arrange items like this

[image: sample ui]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Post the XAML you currently have

Answer (score 1):

I would implement it using a `Grid` with the following layout:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="SecondColumn" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="ThirdColumn" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   ...
</Grid>
```

Now using the [`PaneClosing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.splitview.paneclosing) and [`PaneOpening`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.splitview.paneopening) events to just change the `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` values of the buttons appropriately.

So when pane is open, I would set:

- `Grid.Row` to 0 for all three buttons
- `Grid.Column` to 0, 1, 2 respectively
- `SecondColumn.Width` and `ThirdColumn.Width` to `new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)`

And when closed:

- `Grid.Row` to 0, 1, 2 respectively
- `Grid.Column` to 0 for all three buttons
- `SecondColumn.Width` and `ThirdColumn.Width` to `new GridLength(0)`

Alternative solution would be to use a `StackPanel` and just switch its `Orientation` between `Horizontal` and `Vertical`, although that would not put the buttons right next to each other - to add the spaces, you would have to modify the `Margin` of the buttons too.

Comment: you have any sample for this

Comment: Well, the answer is basically the sample :-D . There is everything you need to do in the code. What are you missing? Could you also please post the current XAML code you have?